# .Net Framework + Core Template application deploy to cloud Foundary

Tags: asp.net-core, cloud-foundry, asp.net-core-webapi

Good day All,I am working  on a ASP.NET application core template with .Net framework. I have to publish my application to cloud foundry.But unfortunately my application is crashing and not able to deploy to cloud foundry environment.Anyone if come across the same situation and resolved the issue please suggest.Thanks. I have gone through some websites and tried modify as below still not able to deploy. I am using .NetCoreBuild pack for the deployment.

```
Program.cs:-

 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddCommandLine(args)
               .Build();
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
               //.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               //.UseIISIntegration()
               .UseConfiguration(config)
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
Project.Json:-

{
  "buildOptions": {
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "**/*.cshtml",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "bin",
        "obj"
      ]
    },
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "bin",
      "obj"
    ]
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.3"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
},

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "dotnet bundle" ]
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.301",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "version": "1.0.3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your project.json file you're specifying:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net461": { }
}
```

The `net461` refers to .NET Framework 4.6.1, but the .NET Core buildpack only supports .NET Core.  Use `netcoreapp1.0` instead of `net461`, like so:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your response but I am using .Net framework with core template.In this scenario kindly suggest which build pack shall I use.